# TreeSet comparator based on mutable attribute

Tags: java, data-structures, treeset

My problem is very basic, but I have no clue how to solve it correctly. I have a TreeSet which uses a comparator based on the name of the entity. However, I can change that name. How do I force a reordering of the TreeSet?

```
TreeSet<MyEntity> set = new TreeSet<MyEntity>(new BeanComparator("name"));
// bar < foo < xander
set.add(foo);
set.add(bar);
set.add(xander);
// resulting tree:     _-foo-_
//                   bar    xander
xander.setName("apple");

set.contains(xander); // -> false, since now neither 'foo' or 'bar' are equal to 'xander'
```

Is there some `set.relayout()` method I should be calling, or am I going about this all wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a link to the TreeSet when you changing the name of elements, just remove that element from the set, change its name, and insert back.

If you don't have that link at the time of updating name, then I'd suggest to have it as a private field in MyEntity, and rewrite setName() as

```
public class MyEntity {
  private final TreeSet<MyEntity> container;

  ...

  public void setName(final String name) {
    container.remove(this);
    this.name = name;
    container.add(this);
  }
}
```

But, this approach is very ugly. You'd better avoid it.

Answer (score 2):

+1 for finding out why your search is not working. It is almost always wrong to allow a key to be mutable in a keyed collection.

There is no `set.relayout` method. Even if there was, you would need on the `client code` to do the right thing and that is very error-prone.

So you need to remove the element and add it back in, which is also equally error-prone. One alternative is to make `MyEntity` observable and `extend TreeSet` so that it gets notified of changes which it responds to by removing and adding the element.

There may still be concurrency concerns though, one way to solve it is for `MyEntity` to notify the container with `beforeChange` and `afterChange`